# HTTP GET: Check if var is empty

Tags: php, variables, get, isset

I have a form that outputs the following http string when the the form is submitted:

> Field109=E01&Field112=E05&Field209=Enter+the+message+here%21&Field110=&Field111=&Field113=&Field114=&Field115=&Field116=&Field117=&Field118=&Field119=&Field120=&CreatedBy=public&DateCreated=2013-01-17+08%3A43%3A45&EntryId=14&IP=98.246.50.81&HandshakeKey=

In my PHP script that handles the submission, I check each Field to see if it is set.
The problem is, as you can see above, if the field in the form is empty when submitting, it still remains in the HTTP string and `isset()` thinks it is set and does processing I tell it to.

How do I check to see if the field is truly empty? For example `Field110` and `Field111` should be empty, but my PHP script thinks they are set.

```
if (isset($_GET["Field110"])) {
    array_push($apnsarray, "E02");
}
if (isset($_GET["Field111"])) {
    array_push($apnsarray, "E03");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `empty()`

```
if(!empty($_GET['Field110'])){
    array_push($apnsarray, "E02");
}
// etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I check to see if the field is truly empty?

[`empty()`](http://php.net/empty)

`isset()` *determines if a variable is set and is not NULL*. Whereas `empty()` will check if the value is *empty*.

So in your case `isset()` is returning true by the definition above. Instead use `empty()` for the values that require a value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what are the possible values? 
If it might have a 0 and only a 0 in it, I'd recommend this:

```
if(isset($_GET['Field110']) && strlen(trim($_GET['Field110']) != 0) {
    // not empty
}
```

But if it's only ever gonna consist of letters or something that isn't 0:

```
if(!empty($_GET['Field110'])) {
    //not empty
}
```

This is from the `empty()` doc:

```
The following things are considered to be empty:

"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)
```

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)